# write a query to select of all the employees who are managers

Tags: mysql

table schema

salaries
emp_no, salary, from_date, to_date

dept_manager
emp_no, dept_no, from_date, to _date

TO get Average salary of all the employee who are managers

Comment: Please review https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and publish what you have done so far.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The sql code is:

```
SELECT AVG(salary) AS salary_avg
FROM dept_manager
INNER JOIN salaries
ON salaries.emp_no = dept_manager.emp_no
```

In tables you posted, all employees are managers, there is no difference on employees role